# Calling method on subslice without reference

Tags: methods, reference, rust

Normally in Rust, you can't assign a (sub)slice of something to a local variable without taking its reference since a `str` has unknown size:

```
let s = "hello";
let x = s[..]; // doesn't compile
let y = &s[..]; // ok
```

However, I noticed you can call a method directly on a slice:

```
let x = s[..].to_owned(); // ok
let y = (&s[..]).to_owned(); // ok
```

Is there any difference between the two ways, in terms of semantics and performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to Rust's auto-ref rules. When you call a method that takes `&self` (such as `to_owned`) on a value  instead of a reference, Rust will automatically take a reference in order to call the method.

The code compiles because there is never a time that the unsized type is accessed except via a reference.